# how to separate each object output using map method - React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this code structure:

```
[
  [
    { title: 'McRoyale', price: 70, count:5, totalPrice: 350 },
    { title: 'Big Mac', price: 55, count:1, totalPrice: 55 },
  ],
  [
    { title: 'Double Big Tasty', price: 99, count:2, totalPrice: 198 },
  ],
  [
    { title: 'Grand Chicken Premier', price: 72, count:3, totalPrice: 216 },
    { title: 'Spicy Chicken Fillet', price: 60, count:2, totalPrice: 120 },
  ]
]
```

array of three arrays -maybe more or less than three it's dynamic number- each one of these arrays consists of arrays of objects

I wrote this code:

```
<thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope='col'>Items</th>
            <th scope='col'>Total Items Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {cardItems.map((items) =>
            items.map((item) => (
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <b>Item:</b> {item.title}, <b>Item Price:</b> {item.price},{' '}
                  <b>Item Count:</b>
                  {item.count}, <b>Item Total Price:</b> {item.totalPrice}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and I got this output:

[image]

but this is not the output I needed, I need each inner array to be in one  not each item alone, I want to separate it by objects, like this:

[image]

each object together in one row.

Comment: When u say each object together in a row , means u want it to be comma separated   the actual output you need is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 <tbody>
        {cardItems.map((items) => (
          <tr>
            <td>
              {items.map((item) => (
                <>
                  <b>Item:</b> {item.title}, <b>Item Price:</b> {item.price},{" "}
                  <b>Item Count:</b>
                  {item.count}, <b>Item Total Price:</b> {item.totalPrice}{" "}
                </>
              ))}
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
</tbody>
```